# Solaris difference between 's' and 'l' in permissions

Tags: files, permissions, solaris, chmod

On a Solaris 11 machine, when I execute `chmod 2000 myfile`, I get `l` instead of `S` or `s`:

```
touch myfile && chmod 2000 myfile && ls -l myfile
------l---. 1 pydoge pydoge 0 Oct 16 12:35 myfile
```

But when I execute `chmod 2010`, I get what I was expecting:

```
touch myfile && chmod 2010 myfile && ls -l myfile
------s---. 1 pydoge pydoge 0 Oct 16 12:35 myfile
```

Why is that? On my Linux machine:

```
[pydoge@leninovo tmp] $ touch myfile && chmod 2000 myfile && ll myfile
------S---. 1 pydoge pydoge 0 Oct 16 12:35 myfile
```

Comment: This has to do with mandatory locking. See the Solaris manual for `chmod`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may like to check the Solaris man page for `chmod`:

http://schillix.sourceforge.net/man/man1/chmod.1.html

and for `ls`:

http://schillix.sourceforge.net/man/man1/ls.1.html

Mandatory locking `l` is in effect on a regular file when the `x` bit is not set while the `set group-ID` bit is set.

If the `x` bit is set at the same time as the `set group-ID` bit, this really means set group id.

Comment: What is strange, though, is that this is a part of a test that I'm maintaining... We chmod something to 2000 on Linux, Solaris, and HPUX, and check for s or S being the only perm set. This started failing on Oct. 8th, so 8 days ago... How was it ever passing if this is a regular feature..? :/

Comment: Solaris behaves this way since more than 25 years.

Comment: IMHO, it would be more authoritative to link to the Oracle Solaris pages instead of to a sourceforge page, particularly if you're claiming that they are "the Solaris man page"...

Comment: [man ls](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E18752_01/html/816-5165/ls-1.html) and [man chmod](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E18752_01/html/816-5165/chmod-1.html)

Comment: It is the OpenSolaris man page, what problems do you have with them?

Comment: Because it’s a sourceforge site not the Oracle Solaris site.

Comment: As said, this did not change since a long time and it may be helpful to see that it is in the OpenSolaris man pages already.